# Perl Net::SSH2 scp_put returns unknown error

Tags: perl

I am using Net:SSH2 to put file on a remote server with scp_put.
It returns unknown error:

> -43, LIBSSH2_ERROR_UNKNOWN(-43), SCP failure

It seems that the error comes after some timeout/delay, as it takes several minutes to return.

Connection to sftp-server is working. I can get a directory list from the directory.

I have access rights to that directory as I can put files there with SFTP-client.

I am using Strawberry Perl in Windows environment.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::SSH2;

my $dir1 = '.';
my $file = 'D:\\test\\test.txt';
my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
$ssh2->connect('testserver') or die "Unable to connect Host $@ \n";
$ssh2->auth_password('test','test') or die "Unable to login $@ \n";

if($ssh2->scp_put($file, $dir1)) {
            print "File $file transferred to $dir1\n";
} else {
            print "Couldn't transfer file $file to $dir1\n";
            print join ', ', $ssh2->error;
            print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you use a full path for the remote (eg: '/home/user') as opposed to the cwd (`.`)?

Comment: No difference when using full path. Directory listing works with cwd(.) and full path, scp_put does not work.

Comment: I will probably have to try NET::SFTP:Foreign. We don’t have it installed at the current Perl setup we have in production. That’s why I was trying to manage it with libssh2 and scp_put.

Answer (score 1):

SCP support in libssh2 is quite rudimentary and buggy.

Better alternatives are [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Any) which has a proper pure-perl implementation of SCP or [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign) for SFTP. Both can work on top of [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2).